# Get user data on a POST request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I just starting to learn laravel and i don't know how to pass data on controller

this is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'view@index');
Route::get('/create', 'view@create');
Route::get('/store', 'view@store');
Route::post('/destroy', 'view@destroy');
```

and this is my controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

use App\Http\Request;

class view extends Controller {


    public function index()
    {
       echo $data = User::all();
    }


    public function create()
    {
        $user =  User::create(['first_Name'=>'abc']);
        echo "id =".$user->id." is created";
    }

    public function store()
    {
        echo "store";
    }

    /* here i want to get id using post request */

    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        echo $id;
    }

}
```

now I want to pass 'id' using postman in post request. how can i perform this. my get request working perfectly

Comment: i want to print id input by user

Comment: you can use: `$request->input('id');` (assuming that your input has the name `id`)

Answer (score 1):

In Postman, you can fill the request body:

[image: Postman example]

The `id` key corresponds to the 'id' argument inside `$request->input('id');`

**Note:** My example uses `DELETE`, which is *common practice*  for destroy/delete actions. In *your* case, it should be `POST`. I do, however, advice you to use `DELETE`.

Comment: it's showing "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: Please provide the error from `laravel.log` in your question. I also updated my answer, because I forgot to mention the `DELETE` request type.

Comment: @Manojkumar If you found this answer helpful, please accept it, so other people can find the answer easier.